# PowerShell: Append Results into single csv

Tags: powershell, append, export-to-csv

I have a script that runs against our scheduling program that will grab job name and location paths for each job in a folder. To get my script to export all jobs in the directory, I include the "$results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details" within the foreach statement that iterates all jobs in the folder, not doing this will only return the last job and path as those were the last to be defined.

My issue is when I add another directory. The first directory will iterate against the second, so the csv prints all jobs in the second dir once for each job in the first. To get around that I want to run each directory independently of eachother, appending the results into a single csv file. Please advise on how to do that.

```
$results = @()
#Create new Job Scheduler Object and connect to Job Scheduler
$SchedulerObject = New-Object -ComObject "ActiveBatch.AbatJobScheduler"; 
$SchedulerObject.Connect("JOBSERVER");


#Trade Support Schedules
$JobObjects1 = $SchedulerObject.Search("/TradeSupport/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
foreach($JobObject1 in $JobObjects1){

    $Jobs1 = $JobObject1.getAbatObject();
    foreach($Job1 in $Jobs1){
        write-host("Name :" + $Job1.Name)
        write-host("Path :" + $Job1.Path)
    }
    #Operations Schedules
    $JobObjects2 = $SchedulerObject.Search("/Operations/Objects/Schedules/","*",65535,"*",$true);
    foreach($JobObject2 in $JobObjects2){
        $Jobs2 = $JobObject2.getAbatObject();
        foreach($Job2 in $Jobs2){
            write-host("Name :" + $Job2.Name)
            write-host("Path :" + $Job2.Path)
        }
        $details = @{
                TradeSupport_Schedule_Name = $Job1.Name
                TradeSupport_Schedule_Path = $Job1.FullPath
                Operations_Schedule_Name = $Job2.Name
                Operations_Schedule_Path = $Job2.FullPath
                BackOffice_Schedule_Name = $BOSchedName
                BackOffice_Schedule_Path =$BOSchedPath
        }
        $results += New-Object PSObject -Property $details

     write-host("************************************************************")
    }
}
$results | select-object -property TradeSupport_Schedule_Name,TradeSupport_Schedule_Path,Operations_Schedule_Name,Operations_Schedule_Path | export-csv -Path \\computer\c$\Support\AB_Reports\Objects_Report.csv -NoTypeInformation 
$SchedulerObject.Disconnect();
```

Comment: Sounds like you are trying to solve the wrong problem. From what you have told us, what you have is an improperly setup loop. You should be looking to fix that first.
Sure, trying to write data to a csv file could achieve what you want but your script would still be faulty. The `-Append` parameter on the `Export-csv` is what you are looking for. But you still have to figure out the best way to call the export command or you will just end up having the same problem.

My suggestion is to fix your loop problem.

Comment: I am not sure what you are referring to, care to explain how my loop is broken? Thanks.

Comment: It is my imagination that this script was designed to work for 1 director[$JobObjects1]. You must have replicated the same lines for a second directory [$JobObjects2]. But you did that inside the for loop of the first. Hence, your 2nd directory is iterated once for every $JobObject 1 in the first.

Comment: You are correct. In a way, fixing this issue is included in the answer I am hoping to receive. I am not sure how to define these two separate loops in a way that they will both iterate through their entire directories then export results.

Comment: Hmm, so, essentially what you need is a csv file with 6 headers as mentioned in the $details array. Although, I do not see a connection between the data of the 2 directories that makes it imperative to have them side by side. Wouldn't the number of jobs in each directories be different and cause mismatch? Also, the backoffice~ jobs do not seem to change its value so would be constant in every line?